# Checkout Button Missing

Tags: commerce

I have a Drupal site that I upgraded from Drupal 7 using Commerce module to the latest version of Drupal and Commerce.  Things did not go as expected.  The view for the shopping cart form and block were both empty.  So I spun up a new install and copied the fields into those.  It shows them now.  The only problem is there is no checkout button.  Just an update cart button.  In the admin section under order types the Shopping Cart Settings both the form view and block view is blank with no options in the drop down.  How can I get this working?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you set up a checkout flow at /admin/commerce/config/checkout-flows/?

Comment: Yes there is one called default and one called paypal checkout

Comment: Okay, that's good. How about order types? That's where you /admin/commerce/config/order-types/ indicate which checkout flow will be used.